# Data Source file cannot be saved Soap Service Connection

Tags: 2013, ssl, soap, uls, sharepoint-designer

I am trying to Get List Items using SharePoint Designer 2013 Soap Service Data Source.
I have entered Service description as 
`https://sitesurl/_vti_bin/lists.asmx?WSDL`

listName as:D8999D5E-BF61-46FC-A459-6FBA32FE7893
[image]

Connection is sucessfully made if i use Farm Admin or Privileaged account of the AD Sharepoint Server is hooked up to. If i use regular Domain User with Site owners permission i get this error message.

In similar event where i am trying to run updatelistitems operation from powershell from diffrent server, i receive following error:
[enter link description here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/110846/could-not-establish-trust-relationship-for-the-ssl-tls-secure-channel-sharepoint)

```
New-WebServiceProxy : The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for  the SSL/TLS secure channel
```

Are these two incident related with each other. If so hwo can i resolve this issue. i checked by ULS log at time of incident i cant see exceptions or error.

All of my site collections are using https protocol 443 port and secured by verisign wilcard certificate.

Thank you